# Decode Japanese Characters to Base64

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, base64, decode

I have a little bit complicated problem about decoding...
I have a code that takes notes from gmail (taken by siri) and insert them to variable and compare `len` of word to know if the word is in the `keywords` list - another .py file

Problem is that the gmail changes Japanese character `車` to `6luk` and it doesn't match... Even if I change `keywords` .py file word `車` to `6luk` it doesn't work.... It works only if I write that `6luk` to the code directly.
`6luk` can change to `車` when I use a

```
    base64.b64decode(command).decode('utf-8')
```

but because it already doing decode in

```
   voice_command = email.message_from_string(data[0][1].decode('utf-8'))
```

it doesn't works well.... I could delete that `.decode('utf-8')` from there, but it will not works at all ...
I tried to decode variable `command` which contain `6luk` from the gmail to `base64` which works online (decode sites), even in another file with

```
   base64.b64decode(command).decode('utf-8')
```

but it wont works within `command` variable.
 It says this

```
   The word(s) '6luk' have been said
   Received an exception while running: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xea in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

I was searching for `0xea` which looks like Latin-1, but when I convert it to `Latin-1` it becomes even more complicated: `ê[¤`

Here is the code, which is a part of

```
    hackster.io/thesanjeetc/siricontrol-add-siri-voice-control-to-any-project-644b52
```

project

Btw. the raw note in gmail, looks like this

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
From:  <@gmail.com>
X-Uniform-Type-Identifier: com.apple.mail-note
Mime-Version: 1.0 (iOS/12.2 \(-----\) dataaccessd/1.0)
Date: Thu, 25 Apr 2019 11:42:33 +0900
X-Mail-Created-Date: Thu, 25 Apr 2019 11:42:33 +0900
Subject: 車
X-Universally-Unique-Identifier: --------
Message-Id: <-------@gmail.com>

6LuK
```

```py
import time
import imaplib
import email
import os
import pkgutil
import base64

##########################################

# Add your gmail username and password here

username = ""
password = ""

##########################################


class ControlException(Exception):
    pass


class Control():
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        print("------------------------------------------------------")
        print("-                    SIRI CONTROL                    -")
        print("-           Created by Sanjeet Chatterjee            -")
        print("-      Website: https://medium.com/@thesanjeetc      -")
        print("------------------------------------------------------")

        try:
            self.last_checked = -1
            self.mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com", 993)
            self.mail.login(username, password)
            self.mail.list()
            self.mail.select("Notes")

            # Gets last Note id to stop last command from executing
            result, uidlist = self.mail.search(None, "ALL")
            try:
                self.last_checked = uidlist[0].split()[-1]
            except IndexError:
                pass

            self.load()
            self.handle()
        except imaplib.IMAP4.error:
            print("Your username and password is incorrect")
            print("Or IMAP is not enabled.")

    def load(self):
        """Try to load all modules found in the modules folder"""
        print("\n")
        print("Loading modules...")
        self.modules = []
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "modules")
        directory = pkgutil.iter_modules(path=[path])
        for finder, name, ispkg in directory:
            try:
                loader = finder.find_module(name)
                module = loader.load_module(name)
                if hasattr(module, "commandWords") \
                        and hasattr(module, "moduleName") \
                        and hasattr(module, "execute"):
                    self.modules.append(module)
                    print("The module '{0}' has been loaded, "
                          "successfully.".format(name))
                else:
                    print("[ERROR] The module '{0}' is not in the "
                          "correct format.".format(name))
            except:
                print("[ERROR] The module '" + name + "' has some errors.")
        print("\n")

    def fetch_command(self):
        """Retrieve the last Note created if new id found"""
        self.mail.list()
        self.mail.select("Notes")

        result, uidlist = self.mail.search(None, "ALL")
        try:
            latest_email_id = uidlist[0].split()[-1]
        except IndexError:
            return

        if latest_email_id == self.last_checked:
            return

        self.last_checked = latest_email_id
        result, data = self.mail.fetch(latest_email_id, "(RFC822)")
        voice_command = email.message_from_string(data[0][1].decode('utf-8'))
        return str(voice_command.get_payload()).lower().strip()

    def handle(self):
        """Handle new commands

        Poll continuously every second and check for new commands.
        """
        print("Fetching commands...")
        print("\n")

        while True:
            try:
                command = self.fetch_command()
                if not command:
                    raise ControlException("No command found.")

                print("The word(s) '" + command + "' have been said")
                command = base64.b64decode(command)
                command = (command.decode('Latin-1'))
                command = base64.b64encode(command).encode('utf-8')
                command = base64.b64encode(command).decode('utf-8')
                print(command)
                for module in self.modules:
                    foundWords = []
                    for word in module.commandWords:
                        if str(word) in command:
                            foundWords.append(str(word))
                    if len(foundWords) == len(module.commandWords):
                        try:
                            module.execute(command)
                            print("The module {0} has been executed "
                                  "successfully.".format(module.moduleName))
                        except:
                            print("[ERROR] There has been an error "
                                  "when running the {0} module".format(
                                      module.moduleName))
                    else:
                        print("\n")
            except (TypeError, ControlException):
                pass
            except Exception as exc:
                print("Received an exception while running: {exc}".format(
                    **locals()))
                print("Restarting...")
            time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Control(username, password)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The body you retrieve with `imaplib` is a `bytes` object.  There is no need to `decode` that in order to pass it to `b64decode`;

```
>>> base64.b64decode(b'6Luk')
b'\xe8\xbb\xa4'
```

This is the UTF-8 encoding of the character [U+8ECA](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/8eca/index.htm) so the next step is to decode it.

```
>>> base64.b64decode(b'6Luk').decode('utf-8')
'軤'
```

How exactly to fix your code is a good question. I would change `fetch_command` to return the actual decoded string from the payload, since you already have a number of assumptions in that function about what inputs you expect.

Without access to your infrastructure, I don't really have a good way to test this, but off the cuff, perhaps something like

```
    def fetch_command(self):
        """Retrieve the body of the last Note created if new id found"""
        self.mail.list()
        self.mail.select("Notes")

        result, uidlist = self.mail.search(None, "ALL")
        try:
            latest_email_id = uidlist[0].split()[-1]
        except IndexError:
            return

        if latest_email_id == self.last_checked:
            return

        self.last_checked = latest_email_id
        result, data = self.mail.fetch(latest_email_id, "(RFC822)")
        # use message_from_bytes instead of attempting to decode something which almost certainly isn't UTF-8
        note = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])
        # extract body part
        voice_command = note.get_payload(decode=True)
        return voice_command.lower().strip()

    def handle(self):
        """Handle new commands

        Poll continuously every second and check for new commands.
        """
        print("Fetching commands...")
        #print("\n")   # empty output lines are an annoyance up with which I will not put

        while True:
            try:
                command = self.fetch_command()
                if not command:
                    raise ControlException("No command found.")

                print("The word(s) '" + command + "' have been said")
                #print(command)
                # etc etc
```

If your Python is new enough (3.3+ really, but properly speaking from 3.6 onward, which is when the new API became the default) you will probably want to investigate using the new `email` library features with `email.policy` instead of the legacy interface.

```
   from email.policy import default
   # ....
        note = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1], policy=default)
        voice_command = note.get_body()
```

You'll notice that we let the `email` library figure out what to decode and how. We avoid hardcoding anything like `utf-8` or `base64` because a different piece of text could come through with a different character set and/or a different transfer encoding. You have to examine and obey the MIME headers for each individual message part. (We *are* hardcoding an expectation that there will be a single payload. I'm not entirely sure this is a robust assumption, either.)

Incidentally, this message formatting is not in particular a feature of GMail, it is how MIME encapsulates content to keep it compatible with the fundamentally 7-bit ASCII-only RFC822 email message format.